# AudioKit AKPlayer isLooping doesn't work without buffer bufferLooping, intended?

Tags: audiokit

I'm working with the AudioKit Playgrounds, and I've noticed that the "Connecting Nodes" Playground doesn't loop without bufferLooping enabled. I looked at a few other playgrounds, and this seems to be universally true. Is anyone else seeing this?

- XCode 9.3
- AudioKit 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this bug in AKPlayer has now been fixed in the [latest development build](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/tree/develop). Also bufferLooping has been removed in favor of buffering = .always. You only need to use buffering if you want a loop to be loaded into ram and be seamless.